# data retreival form database in android

Tags: android, database

In my application i am showing data from database in a listview.In that listview     1 particular text view should be dynamic(i.e) based on one column value that particular textview should change,

Following are my full structure of database:

```
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/bmcrp
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8f13z
```

.In that if reccurence is "true" means textview 9 should show recctotal otherwise total.

My code  is as follows:

```
Cursor c = db.getExpensetitle(intent.getStringExtra("grpsdbexp"));
            startManagingCursor(c);     


                    -------------------->Here i have to use the condition.
                  from = new String[] {db.KEY_DATE,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_QUANTITY,db.KEY_TOTAL,db.KEY_ROWID};
                  to = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text3,R.id.text5,R.id.text7,R.id.text9,R.id.text11};


            SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnviewexp, c, from, to);             
            lv.setAdapter(notes);
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a condition, you should custom cursor adapter instead of SimpleCursorAdapter.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/android-custom-cursoradapter-design

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnviewexp, c, from, to)
{
      @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        boolean reurrence= cursor.getBoolean(cursor.getColumnIndex("recurrence"));

        TextView text9=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text9);

        String text=null;
        if(recurrence)
            text=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TOTAL));
        else
            text=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REC_TOTAL));

         text9.setText(text);

        // Load remaining TextViews

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks jeet.But still i am not clear..I am little bit new to this adapter..So in my above code,what i have to do for check the condition.

Comment: Ya jeet..But in the line  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)     Context can't be resolved into variable ,like that it is showing.What i have to do for that..

Comment: import android.content.Context

Comment: I am extremely sorry,its supporting for me..I will run the code and get back to u..